# Split string by largest regex match

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split a document into different sections. The header of this sections can be

- 1. Header
- I. Header
- A. Part I. Header
- Part I. Header
- Header

I have tried to use a regex that captures all possible beginnings of the header and then split the document by sections but it doesn't return what I expect it to return.

The text is something like this:

```
1. Index
words words
A. Part I. Introduction
words words
4. Information
words words
Conclusion
words words
```

The regex I'm using is:

```
(^(([A-Z]{1}|\d)\.)\s(part (i|ii)(\.\s))?)?(index|introduction|conclusion)$, re.M|re.I
```

The output is:

```
['', '1. ', '1.', '1', None, None, None, 'Index', '\nwords words\n', 'A. Part I. ', 'A.', 'A', 'Part I. ', 'I', '. ', 'Introduction', '\nwords words\n', '4. ', '4.', '4', None, None, None, 'Information', '\nwords words\n', None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Conclusion', '\nwords words\n    ']
```

And my desired output would be something like this, where the text divides by the longest regex match, not by all the matches:

```
['1. Index
words words',
'A. Part I. Introduction
words words',
'4. Information
words words',
'Conclusion
words words']
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You should post a more general sample text so that we better know the splitting logic you want.

Comment: You don't have `information` in your pattern. See if [this demo](https://tio.run/##dZBNC8IwDIbP9leE4mHFORQ9CaOIpx0E787D2OoszLakFT/wv890gh7ES0jePORN4u7hZM2i7/XZWQyAijFUrbpBDshLk8g8kat9NX2UzaHMYEKVqwjUWlIppJCkaBPQNpc6aGue2hwtnqshr62pu4t/y426ibHgjHkanvB5BkXUSsPZiF8tNh6G@BbWGeyiURGx7/g/9DJSH98/0OazzQ/ARbw7LoYq867TIRnekIJPYZbCsatan1Nv@6RQEO2QribIi75/AQ) helps.

Comment: Would parts always be I or II, or is there a potential of more parts consuming more roman numbers?

Answer (score 0):

`^((\w\.\s*)(part (i|ii)\.\s*)?)?(index|introduction|conclusion)$`

The biggest problem was that you had misplaced your `^`.

I also shortened the `([A-Z]{1}|\d)` down to `\w` since it is practically the same.

Lastly, if you want this to work, you should also match the body text (the words words)

```
^((\w\.\s*)(part (i|ii)\.\s*)?)?(index|introduction|conclusion)$(\n(?!((\w\.\s*)(part (i|ii)\.\s*)?)?(index|introduction|conclusion)$).*)*
```